# Ruby on Rails: Concatenate results of Mongoid criterias and paging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something wrong. Consider the following code:

```
criteria1 = Model.where(...)
criteria2 = Model.where(...)
results = (criteria1.to_a + criteria2.to_a)[offset..(offset + count_per_page - 1)]
```

This code concatenates results of two different criterias and get a certain number of results with a given offset (paging).

The problem in this code is implicit. The `to_a` method call actually **loads all results of a criteria to the memory as an array**.

Now consider a really huge collection... The `to_a` call slows all things down dramatically.

What I wish to do is something like this:

```
criteria1 = Model.where(...)
criteria2 = Model.where(...)

# A criteria, which returns results of the first criteria concatenated with results of the second criteria
criteria = criteria1 + criteria2
results = criteria.offset(offset).limit(count_per_page)
```

The important thing is that results of the second criteria goes **after** results of the first criteria.

Any clues how is it possible to achieve with Mongoid?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Gergo Erdosi suggested to use `merge` method. I've tried to use this and it is not what I'm looking for. The problem here is the following:

```
criteria1 = Model.where(:name => "John", :age => "23")
criteria2 = Model.where(:name => "Bob", :gender => "male")
criteria = criteria1.merge(criteria2)
p criteria.selector
# prints: { "name" => "Bob", :age => 23, :gender => "male" }
```

So here are two problems:

1. `merge` doesn't produce OR, it overrides common keys of the first query with the second;
2. Even if we use `Model.or({ :name => "John" }, { :name => "Bob" })` or `Model.in(:name => ["John", "Bob"])` results won't have the right **order**. I wish results of the first criteria go first and then results of the second criteria go **after**.

It is possible that I don't understand something and Gergo's answer is right. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks.

**UPDATE 2**

Thank you Gergo for helping me out here. Let's try a simple example in Mongo shell:

```
// Fill out test db with some simple documents.
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { db.users.insert({ name: i % 2 ? "John" : "Bob", age: Math.round(Math.random() * 100) }); }

// These queries give me the same order of documents.
db.users.find({ name: { $in: ["Bob", "John"] } });
db.users.find({ $or: [{ name: "Bob" }, { name: "John" }] });

// Like this:
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53732076b110ab9be7619a8e"), "name" : "Bob", "age" : 69 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53732076b110ab9be7619a8f"), "name" : "John", "age" : 63 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53732076b110ab9be7619a90"), "name" : "Bob", "age" : 25 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53732076b110ab9be7619a91"), "name" : "John", "age" : 72 }
// ...

// But I wish to get concatenated results of these queries:
db.users.find({ name: "Bob" });
db.users.find({ name: "John" });

// Like this (results of the first criteria go first):
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53732076b110ab9be7619a8e"), "name" : "Bob", "age" : 69 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53732076b110ab9be7619a90"), "name" : "Bob", "age" : 25 }
// ...
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53732076b110ab9be7619a8f"), "name" : "John", "age" : 63 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53732076b110ab9be7619a91"), "name" : "John", "age" : 72 }
// ...
```

Notice, that I cannot use a simple sorting here, because the data in the real application is more complex. In the real application criterias look like these:

```
// query variable is a string
exact_match_results = Model.where(:name => query)
inexact_match_results = Model.where(:name => /#{query}/i)
```

So we cannot just sort alphabetically here.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `merge` method:

```
criteria = criteria1.merge(criteria2)
results = criteria.offset(offset).limit(count_per_page)
```

You can see the details in the [method description](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb#L254-L278).

**Edit**: As pointed out, `merge` doesn't produce an OR query.

```
irb(main):010:0> Model.where(name: 'John').merge(Model.where(name: 'Bob'))
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"name"=>"Bob"}
  options:  {}
  class:    Model
  embedded: false>
```

Which is not the expected behavior in this case. The reason is that `merge` uses `Hash.merge` which behaves this way. The [relevant](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb#L292) code from `Criteria.merge`:

```
selector.merge!(criteria.selector)
```

This can be illustrated as:

```
irb(main):011:0> {name: 'John'}.merge({name: 'Bob'})
=> {:name=>"Bob"}
```

Because of this, it's not easy to give a general advice on how to merge two criteria in a way that the result is an OR query. But with a little change in the criteria, it's possible. For example:

```
criteria1 = Model.any_of(name: 'John').where(age: '23')
criteria2 = Model.any_of(name: 'Bob').where(gender: 'male')
```

The result of the merge is an OR query which contains both names:

```
irb(main):014:0> criteria1.merge(criteria2)
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {"$or"=>[{"name"=>"John"}, {"name"=>"Bob"}], "age"=>"23", "gender"=>"male"}
  options:  {}
  class:    Model
  embedded: false>
```

Comment: @GeorgoErdosi Consider results of the first criteria are [2, 4, 8] and result of the second criteria are [1, 3, 7]. I need to get page of concatenated results: [2, 4, 8, 1, 3, 7]. So it is important to have such order, because results of the second criteria are less relevant, than results of the first criteria (I need this for the search feature in my project). But I cannot concatenate results without casting Mongoid criterias to arrays, what is bad in case of huge Mongo collections.

Comment: I get what you want, I just don't understand why it is a problem. `{"$or"=>[{"name"=>"John"}, {"name"=>"Bob"}], "age"=>"23", "gender"=>"male"}` is the same as `{"$or"=>[{"name"=>"John"}, {"name"=>"Bob"}], "gender"=>"male", "age"=>"23"}`. Can you give me a real example?

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand it. Data in the database is not ordered. If you want to get an ordered list, then you need to sort by something. This query works too: `db.users.find({ name: /(bob|john)/i }).sort({ name: 1})`.

Comment: Please, look at the end of my post again. We may have a collection of names: `[ "Bob", "Good Bob", "Bob", "Bob the Best", "Evil Bob", "Bob", "Bob" ]`. First criteria gets exact match of names: `[ "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob" ]`, but the second gets all names with "Bob" substring. And I need to sort results by relevance (first exact match and then inexact match): `[ "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Bob", "Good Bob", "Bob the Best", "Evil Bob" ]`. I cannot sort these results alphabetically. It should be ordered by relevance.