# Ordering Collection by multiple fields and condition in Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have 4 fields in a document which is `name`, `online`, `like` and `score`. I want to ordering by multiple fields and conditions collection of million documents with pagination.

Example some documents :

My user documents :

```
{ "_id": 1, "name": "A", "online": 1, "like": 10, "score": 1 },
{ "_id": 2, "name": "B", "online": 0, "like": 9, "score": 0 },
{ "_id": 3, "name": "C", "online": 0, "like": 8, "score": 1 },
{ "_id": 4, "name": "D", "online": 1, "like": 8, "score": 0 },
{ "_id": 5, "name": "E", "online": 1, "like": 7, "score": 1 },
{ "_id": 6, "name": "F", "online": 0, "like": 10, "score": 0 },
```

I will explain my point with the following example (example using an array).

Example in ruby language, I have an array structure looks like :

```
[["A", 1, 10, 1],
["B", 0, 9, 1],
["C", 0, 8, 1],
["D", 1, 8, 0],
["E", 1, 7, 1],
["F", 0, 10, 0]]
```

If `online` is `1` should be sort again by descending of `like`, but when `online` is `0` should be sort again by descending of `score`.

example sort :

```
list.sort{|a, b| a[1] == 1 ? ([-a[1], -a[2]] <=> [-b[1], -b[2]]) : ([-a[1], -a[3]] <=> [-b[1], -b[3]]) }
```

Result like this :

```
[["A", 1, 10, 1],
["D", 1, 8, 0],
["E", 1, 7, 1],
["B", 0, 9, 1],
["C", 0, 8, 1],
["F", 0, 10, 0]]
```

That is an array sort, but my problem is I have collection of mongodb and million documents, I can't use an array sort, because it will heavy load to database, should get all documents and convert to array (including sorting) and than paginate them, I think that's a bad idea.

I have try with `order()`/`order_by()` mongoid's optional method like :

```
User.
order_by([:online, :desc], [:like, :desc], [:score, :desc]).
hint(online: -1, like: -1, score: -1).
page(1).per(10)
```

But that query is only order by `online` and `score`, is there sort method in mongoid like an array sorting? or there is something like bubble sort in mongodb?

same problem here : [Ruby on Rails: Concatenate results of Mongoid criterias and paging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23638357/1297435), `merge` method doesn't helped me because it can be replace the first criteria.

Comment: Have you tried `order` like in this query ? `User.where(speciality_id: { '$ne': nil }, is_deleted: false).order(online: :desc, like: :desc, score: :desc).hint(speciality_id: 1, is_deleted: 1, online: -1, like: -1, score: -1).
page(1).per(10)`

Comment: May be do it in multiple queries. Like fetching only online documents sorted by likes first. And if needed, fetch non-online documents sorted by score.

Comment: @shiko yes I have tried that query, not suitable result, I mean, the last sort is based on score when `online` is `1`

Comment: @JagdeepSingh do you mean the first query is sorting by `like` and than the second query sorting by `score` but check first if the result of first query is under of limit documents?

Comment: Exactly that's what i mean

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I think that's a complicated solution for pagination, too much logical for total pages and records.

Answer (score 2):

Using aggregation `$cond`

```
User.collection.aggregate([
      { 
        "$project" => {
            "id" => 1, 
            "name" => 1, 
            "online" => 1, 
            "like" => 1, 
            "score" => 1,
            "sort" => {
                "$cond" => {
                   "if" => { 
                      "$eq" => ["$online", 1] 
                   },
                   "then" => "$like",
                   "else" => "$score"
                }
            }
       }
     },
     { 
        "$sort" => {
            "online" => -1,  
            "sort" => -1,
            "id" => 1
        }
     },
     {
        "$skip" => 0
     { 
        "$limit" => 12 
     }
])
```

references :

1. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/
2. https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/How-to-use-Conditional-Statements-for-sorting-data-in-MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

Assuming fields score , like and online are numeric , based on the condition we can create an auxiliary field that is a sum of online and like or online and score. Following which we can sort on the new field and any other required field.

```
db.collection aggregate([ {"$addFields": {"refCount":{"$cond":{"if":{"$eq":["$online", 1]}, "then":{"$add": ["$online", "$like"]}, "else": {"$add": ["$online", "$score"]} } } }},{ "$sort": { "refCount": -1 ,"id":1} },{"$project":{"id": 1, "name": 1, "online": 1, "like": 1,"score":1}},{ "$limit": 10 } ])
```

The first stage of the pipeline build the auxiliary field **refcount**. This field is then used in $sort along with **id** . In the next stage we have a projection of required fields , followed by limit clause.
Instead of numeric , if these fields were strings, a padded concatenation of fields would be required.